# How can I seamlessly blend these two objects?

Tags: mesh, edges, smooth

How can I blend these two objects (the two arched objects) so that the edges are smooth rather than having a crevice between them?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to remove some edge loops, hard to tell without the wireframe, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added a picture with the wireframe.

Comment: hello please share the file so that we can test